# Toolbar рисует вместо иконки ошибку [gtk]

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk3

Вроде бы всё правильно делаю, в `assets` лежит картинка 64x64. вот код.

```
static void create_app ( ) {
    app_win = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    GtkWidget *toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new ( );
    GtkToolItem *tool_item_2d = gtk_toggle_tool_button_new ( );
    gtk_toggle_tool_button_set_active ( ( GtkToggleToolButton * ) tool_item_2d, TRUE );
    gtk_tool_button_set_icon_name ( ( GtkToolButton * ) tool_item_2d, "assets/2d.svg.png" );
    gtk_toolbar_insert ( ( GtkToolbar * ) toolbar, tool_item_2d, 0 );

    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, toolbar,
            TRUE,
            TRUE,
            FALSE
            );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) app_win, box );
    gtk_widget_show_all ( app_win );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А всё, понял как делать. надо использовать тему иконок и указать путь, где искать иконки. вот код.

```
static void create_app ( ) {
    app_win = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    GtkWidget *toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new ( );
    GtkToolItem *tool_item_2d = gtk_toggle_tool_button_new ( );
    gtk_toggle_tool_button_set_active ( ( GtkToggleToolButton * ) tool_item_2d, TRUE );
    gtk_tool_button_set_icon_name ( ( GtkToolButton * ) tool_item_2d, "2d.svg" );
    gtk_toolbar_insert ( ( GtkToolbar * ) toolbar, tool_item_2d, 0 );

    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, toolbar,
            TRUE,
            TRUE,
            FALSE
            );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) app_win, box );
    gtk_widget_show_all ( app_win );
}

static void g_startup ( GtkApplication *app, gpointer data ) {
    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new ( NULL, FALSE );

    const gchar *paths = "assets";
    theme_icon = gtk_icon_theme_get_default ( );
    gtk_icon_theme_set_search_path ( theme_icon, &paths, 1 );

    create_menu_config ( );
    create_app ( );

    g_main_loop_run ( loop );
}
```